# PlasmidSeeker, a Perl script cannot run because of "permission denied" error

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

After installing [PlasmidSeeker](https://github.com/bioinfo-ut/PlasmidSeeker) on LinuxMint19, I cannot run its Perl script

It is always "Permission denied" although I've given all the permissions to plasmidseeker.pl

```
sudo perl plasmidseeker.pl -d db_w20/ -i TH19_1.filtered.fastq -b cereus-ATCC14579.fasta
```

The output is

> Loading database... Converting sample reads to k-mers... Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistmaker": Permission denied
>   at plasmidseeker.pl line 275. Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare": Permission
>   denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 277. Finding coverage of bacterial
>   isolate... Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistmaker": Permission denied
>   at plasmidseeker.pl line 283. Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare": Permission
>   denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 152. Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare": Permission
>   denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 153. Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare": Permission
>   denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 159. Can't exec
>   "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare": Permission
>   denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 160. Bacteria median coverage is 0
>   Bacteria median coverage is too low (less than 3). Higher coverage
>   dataset is needed or use flag --ponly at plasmidseeker.pl line 287.

I have Googled for possible solutions but found nothing. Could anybody who has some exp with bioinformatics and Perl help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if you remove `sudo` in front of the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've given all the permissions to plasmidseeker.pl

But that's not what the error message is complaining about, is it? Take a closer look.

> Can't exec "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistmaker": Permission denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 275.
>
> Can't exec "/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare": Permission denied at plasmidseeker.pl line 277.

The programs that can't be run are `/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistmaker` and `/home/fox/PlasmidSeeker/GenomeTester4/glistcompare`. Those are the permissions that you need to fix.

It's important to read error messages, of course. But it's more important to understand them :-)